# Screenshot of Debain 8.7 desktop via SSH client running on Android phone

Tags: debian, sshd, display

I am trying to monitor my laptop(Debian 8.7) when it is being used by someone else,I want to see what at any time people are running on my system & for this I m trying to run a terminal command via SSH which captures the screenshot which I can view later.

I am using SSH client named JUICE SSH from my Android Phone to login to my laptop but unable to execute any screenshot related commands.

I have tried `scrot`,`gnome-screenshot`,`import` but unable to get the screenshot the error with `scrot` says `Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?`

I checked my **sshd_config** file it had **X11Forwarding** set to YES searching internet I read that setting it to no should make it work but it did not happened either.

`echo $DISPLAY var is :0.0`

Ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to take a screenshot using the android terminal:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 import -window root screenshot.png
```

Comment: I tried this but gives me `display: unable to open X server ' @ display. /some path/.`

Comment: try this android application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot

Comment: is this app dependent thing?I thought some server config problem it was

Comment: @techie_28 there is my `sshd_config` https://pastebin.com/YMSnZRaX

Comment: I have the default one and have not made changes in it ever.I remember `X11Forwarding yes` was set when someone said that it will cause screenshot of phone to be taken instead of the system.I set that to 'no' but it didnt work

Comment: connect bot is also showing the same error i.e `display: unable to open X server ' @ display. /some path/`

Comment: Adding "-silent" removes the beeping sound: `DISPLAY=:0.0 import -silent -window root screenshot.png`

Answer (score 0):

You need privileges to spy on the screen of another user. Start by listing the access cookies of `TARGET_USER`:

```
$ sudo -u TARGET_USER xauth list
[...]
YOURHOST/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  cc9413c4a3db83ef94647cfb2f1c2f4d
[...]
```

Choose the display you need (for the primary X console it's typically like the above line) and add it to your access list:

```
$ xauth add YOURHOST/unix:0 . cc9413c4a3db83ef94647cfb2f1c2f4d
```

(`.` is an abbreviation of `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1`). You can then dump the display into a file (`:0` is an abbreviation of `YOURHOST/unix:0`):

```
$ xwd -display :0 -root -silent -out root0.xwd
```

or show it directly if you've got your own X display (probably not if you SSH in from an Android system):

```
$ xwd -display :0 -root -silent | xwud
```